# How can I break out of this flow in this dialogflow ES conversation?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying create a chatbot that can give the user a quiz. I have 10 questions and this is how I implemented it:

1. The phrase "I want a quiz" leads to the first question
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

2.The next input by the user can be classified as right or wrong intent. Both of these intents have the same input and output contexts where the input context is the output context of the first question.

INTENT FOR THE RIGHT RESPONSE
[image]
[image]
[image]

INTENT FOR THE WRONG RESPONSE (note that I am using the sys.any entity)
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have 10 questions implemented like this and currently the user has to complete these 10 questions before breaking out of the quiz.

I want to implement a intent that allows the user to end the quiz by typing a messaging such as "end quiz"
I have tried several methods with none of them successful. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can refer to this [doc](https://chatbotslife.com/how-to-create-chatbot-using-dialogflow-66e6ea6bb67d) to create chatbot. Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT thank you for responding, this is only a guide to the basics of dialogflow but it does not answer by question :-)

Comment: To create a Quiz Bot in Dialogflow ES you can check this [documentation](https://botflo.com/how-to-create-a-quiz-bot-in-dialogflow-es/). Let me know if it's helpful or not?